# Embeded HTML post form data in angular application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular11

In third party portal, if we click on button it redirect to my angular application. Issue is when the user click on that button it pass the post data and I want to capture that post data in my angular application. I tried certain ways but it does not seems to work for me. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the form structure which I receive from the third party vendor.

```
<form id="ApplicationRedirectForm" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" name="login" action="http://localhost:4200/" target="_blank">
    <input name="login" value="test" type="hidden">
    <input name="country" value="testcountry" type="hidden">
    <input name="city" value="testcity" type="hidden">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Note: to test it on my local machine I have added button and actions as localhost:4200**

Please let me know if more details are required here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you modify third party code? You can add the data inn cookies and then read it from there.

Comment: No, I don't have access to third party code

Comment: How did you add the redirection then?

Comment: They have shared the form format with me. So that I can embedded the post data in same manner in angular.

Comment: You need to do this from the backend then. Post request cannot be made to frontend

Comment: Oh okay. could you please let me know how it will capture the post data initially when application is being loaded without sending any call from angular?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238383/discussion-between-drashti-dobariya-and-bhushan-khaladkar).